# How express the many to many relationship with single parent table in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have something like a Department, which can have many courses and students. students can be linked to many courses and courses could have many students registered to it. I also want student and courses to be linked to a department.

How can i express this in EF/Fluent API, I have tried these

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasRequired(s => s.Department);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasRequired(u => u.Department);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
                    .HasMany(s => s.Students)
                    .WithOptional()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
                    .HasMany(u => u.Students)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Courses);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                    .HasMany(s => s.Courses)
                    .WithOptional()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

and I tried few other combinations as well, nothing worked and I get this error now

```
The navigation property 'Courses' declared on type 'Models.Student' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities.
```

Any hints/ help?

Update: The student class looks like this

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

and the Course:

```
    public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in order to do a many-to-many like this you need to create a link table between the tables, which you might call `StudentCourses`. Then your `Student` and `Course` classes would have a collection of type `StudentCourse`. Here's how you would create the class (using Data Annotations):

```
public class StudentCourses 
{
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Also, if you still want to be able to grab all students in a course (or all courses that a student is taking), you can do it easily using the `NotMapped` attribute for a public property to get it as follows:

For your `Student` class:

```
[NotMapped]
public List<Course> Courses {
  get { return StudentCourses.Select(sc => sc.Course); }
}
```

For your `Course` class:

```
[NotMapped]
public List<Student> Students {
  get { return StudentCourses.Select(sc => sc.Student); }
}
```

Comment: not necessary, configuring `.HasMany(...).WithMany(...)` will automatically generate the relationship table while preserving the expected `Student.Courses` and `Course.Students` navigation properties

Comment: does this mean I have to load three entities instead of two? (including StudentCourses)?

Comment: If you do it this way, then yes you would. The SQL generated would remain the same, though, since in any case it would need to generate that 3rd table to keep track of the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `.Entity<Department>()` to configure required nav properties to `Department` and specify `.WillCascadeOnDelete( false )` afterwards:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
    .HasMany( d => d.Students )
    .WithRequired()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
    .HasMany( d => d.Courses )
    .WithRequired()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Students)
    .WithMany(s => s.Courses);
```

Comment: That didnt help, i got this error Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.CourseStudents_dbo.Students_Student_Id' on table 'CourseStudents' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: yeah, sorry, remove the WithOptional but move WillCascadeOnDelete down to your existing .HasMany(...).WithMany(...) calls; updated example

Comment: cannot chain WillCascadeOnDelete with WithMany, it doesnt compile

Comment: and if you remove `Course`'s `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` call from my current example, it still gives you the error?

Comment: You use `ICollection<Course>` and configure the property with `.WithMany( s => s.Courses)` so you should not receive a conflicting multiplicities exception.  Originally, you specified `.WithOptional()` which would cause that exception.

Comment: oh i see it now - you're also configuring the relationship via `modelBuilder.Entry<Student>()` - delete that (was it always there?  b/c it doesn't match my example)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41981/discussion-between-dhana-krishnasamy-and-moho)

Comment: I'm surprised, I tested with the entity classes you provided via chat and it solved the error

Comment: I had other issues. WithRequired is not correct as Dept can have no student/courses, so I made it optional. Then next issue is I couldnt get Students from Dept or other way round (dont remember accurately), then if add Student hadrequired dept, then i come back to same issue again. I had two options to relearn FluentAPI, or try separate table, i chose the later